# Add Bootstrap Toast as Alert on SharePoint site

Tags: boot-strap

It will be nice to have a Bootstrap v5.0 Toast as push notification to SharePoint site so to broadcast important message to users.

I tried to put the reference to Bootstrap css and js file in Content editor web part, also tried with content link to a txt file that with toast code and reference to css & js file. However,  either way the web page messed up very bad.

Pls advise if a solution is available?